# JAVA: How to end input with integer "-1"

Tags: java, input, integer

How to end this input when the integer "-1" is being entered.

```
if(op.contains("SENTINEL")){
while(!sc.next.equals("-1")){
String action = sc.next();                                         
int a= sc.nextInt();
int b= sc.nextInt();
int ans=countAns(action, a, b);
System.out.println(+ans);
}}
```

Comment: integer input for which variable in while condition or a or b ?

Comment: integer input for the String action. hence, if i input -1 as the string variable action, the while loop will break.

Answer (score 1):

This loop will be end when you enter `-1` not need anything

but you have syntax error in this part :`!sc.next.equals("-1")` , it should be write like this `!sc.next().equals("-1")`